# Tagged annotation link not reading properly in PDF with JAWS?

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, jaws-screen-reader

What is the problem?

By using PDFBOX I tried to tag a link which contains annotation. The PDF creating sample code is [here](https://github.com/chris271/UAPDFBox/blob/master/src/com/wi/test/util/PDFormBuilder.java). I tagged a nested paragraph link by using PDFBOX. The newly created tagged PDF is passing the Adobe checker.

What I observed?

After tagging pdf I tried to read it using JAWS. But unfortunately the jaws is not reading links in both "entire document mode" and "read currently visible page" mode. Then I jumped to StructTree Root and compared with adobe created tagged PDF vs our tagged PDF. The ParentTree(NUMTree) is not matching with adobe tagged pdf.

[Tagged by me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RQlam80liClhvpHI5WVvjInE0X88S-6l/view?usp=sharing)

[Tagged by Adobe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EApo1mt1WtWu_bZ7EQrAENgz3_OwTEoH/view?usp=sharing)

What I Tried?

I tried to replicate the adobe numtree in my pdf. Almost I am able to create same but except one object. 
[image]

Above image left side is adobe tagged and right side is created by me. I didn't understand the adobe why it is created entire structtree under this (142 O R) object? I am adding annotation object to TumTree by using this code

```html
    private void addWidgetContent(PDObjectReference objectReference, PDStructureElement fieldElem, String type, int pageIndex) {
        COSDictionary annotDict = new COSDictionary();
        COSArray annotArray = new COSArray();
        annotArray.add(COSInteger.get(currentMCID));
        annotArray.add(objectReference);
        annotDict.setItem(COSName.K, annotArray);
        annotDict.setString(COSName.LANG, "EN-US");
        annotDict.setItem(COSName.P, currentElem.getCOSObject());
        annotDict.setItem(COSName.PG, pages.get(pageIndex).getCOSObject());
        annotDict.setName(COSName.S, type);
        annotDicts.add(annotDict);

        setNextMarkedContentDictionary();
        numDictionaries.add(annotDict);
        fieldElem.appendKid(objectReference);
        currentElem.appendKid(fieldElem);
    }
```

And one more bug I saw in Adobe preflight is 
[image]

How can I fix these bugs and what is the correct way of tagging link annotation to be read by JAWS? Please help me .......

I got some update to share. Now I crated parent tree root without having any bugs. Here the file [tagged pdf file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RQlam80liClhvpHI5WVvjInE0X88S-6l/view?usp=sharing).
[image]

Still this tagged pdf not reading links. Why ?????????

Comment: I tried with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59377820/how-to-heal-inconsistent-parent-tree-mappings-in-a-pdf-created-by-pdfbox  still unable to add annotation properly in nums.

Comment: /P is the parent. So it should also be somewhere else, and not a new "entire structtree under this"

Comment: `Root/StructTreeRoot/ParentTree/Nums/[1]` has three null entries then three real entries, was this intended?

Comment: yes, first we auto tagged using adobe and then we added span.

Comment: I looked at the "bnd" file. In the "K" tree, the "link" element ( Root/StructTreeRoot/K/K/[1]/K/[1] ) has as kids the annotation OBJR and "span", whose kid is "5". In the page content stream, "/Span << /MCID 5 >> BDC" designates the link text. In the "res_tagged" file, the link element is at Root/StructTreeRoot/K/K/K/[0] , it has as kids OBJR and 0. So the "span" thing is missing, and you've used "/Link << /MCID 0 >> BDC" for the link text. I'm not saying that is the bug, I'm just noticing the difference.

Comment: Yes, We know that by adjusting spans also we tried but no result. One quick question Tilman, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u9BCYSEsfnhYdhAHCnM-W4y4mE5J3peV/view?usp=sharing see I want to create all numdictionaries like a single new obj. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. You could create an object and have the three objects as kids in the /K entry.